# addEventListener - event vs function intake

Tags: javascript, function, events

Having a bit of trouble understanding why and when I should put in event/function as the second parameter the event listener should be looking for. For example:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', e => {

}
```

vs

```
document.addEventListener('submit',  function whateverName() {

}
```

Comment: The examples are equal. The only difference is `this` handling inside of the callback, but there's no `this` used in the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this example to try to help demonstrate the differences. This mainly comes down to how you access `this` element. Using [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you must provide the `event` so that you can access the element using `e.target`. When using a standard function, you don't need the event and can instead rely on `this` to reference the element tied to the `EventListener`.

The example prints `true` if the elements match. With arrow functions, you will notice the result is `false` because `this` does not exist in context. Standard functions will return `true` because `this` does exist in context.

The arrow functions are exactly the same. I'm just showing that `e` and `(e)` represent the same thing. Review the docs for arrow functions for more on that.

```js
document.getElementById("btn0").addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target==this);
});

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target==this);
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', function() {
  // event is not passed
  console.log(this==this);
});

document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target==this);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn0" type="button">Arrow Function 1</button>
<button id="btn1" type="button">Arrow Function 2</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button">Function 1</button>
<button id="btn3" type="button">Function 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: @toastTea you're welcome. If you feel this answers your question, please mark it as an answer. Same for `Anditya`'s answer. You can mark both as answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your first example

```
document.addEventListener('submit', e => {

}
```

You're passing the event to the function that's handling it in the form of an arrow function. This can be more explicitly written like this.

```
document.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

}
```

If you've multiple parameters to be passed you have to use parentheses the way shown above.

Arrow functions will always execute in the context of the global this and not the scope from which its being invoked.

On the other hand your second example

```
document.addEventListener('submit',  function() {

}
```

is using a classic function. This will always execute in the scope of whatever has called it.

You tend to pass events down to the handler when you need that information (Eg: what exactly was clicked and a reference to that element for a click event) or prevent a default behaviour. The examples you've shown are both submit events. Submit by default reloads the page. This is most often not a desirable behaviour and so you tend to do

```
submitEventHandler(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this!